# Which variable is the equals function camparing Character sets to?

Tags: java, equals, rtf

I was trying to decipher a code written for a text extractor for an RTF. I found a function that contains `if` statements comparing something to character sets with  control words like `ansi` `pc` `mac`. Its like:

```
private void processControlWord() {

if (inHeader) {
            if (equals("ansi")) {
                globalCharset = WINDOWS_1252;
            } else if (equals("pca")) {
                globalCharset = CP850;
            } else if (equals("pc")) {
                globalCharset = CP437;
            } else if (equals("mac")) {
                globalCharset = MAC_ROMAN;
            }
```

and so on...

What is the `equals` function comparing these character sets to? I've seen `somestring.equals(someothersting)` but how is it functioning here?

Comment: An `equals` member method must be in this class hierarchy which takes a Object and returns a boolean.

The written code equals calling `this.equals(...)`

Comment: The equals function is part of the object class, so it just calls it´s own equals method and compares whatever is written in there.

Comment: `equals` is like any other method. It calls an implementation if one exists in the current class else it calls the super's implementation. The chain of calling finally stops at `java.lang.Object`s implementation of `equals`.

Comment: Ohk I found out...They had a user defined function with same name as `equals`. It was overriding the `equals` behaviour. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a user defined function that was overriding the behavior of java's `equals` function.

I don't think that it a good practice to name your functions with the same name as predefined functions. People like me waste a lot of time understanding the code when it comes to maintenence.

Answer (score 0):

See this is how the *equals* method is implemented by default by java

```
 static public boolean areEqual(boolean aThis, boolean aThat){
//System.out.println("boolean");
return aThis == aThat;
```

}

So, according to that 
a.equals(b) has returned true, meaning the condition a==b is satisfied

But in your case its only taking one argument that means , somewhere in your code the equals method has been overloaded.
please refer to this link:
[enter link description here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17)

Answer (score 0):

Calling a method without referencing an object is shorthand for calling it on `this`. So this code could be read as:

```
private void processControlWord() {

    if (inHeader) {
        if (this.equals("ansi")) { // E.g., here
            globalCharset = WINDOWS_1252;
        } else if (this.equals("pca")) {
            globalCharset = CP850;
        } else if (this.equals("pc")) {
            globalCharset = CP437;
        } else if (this.equals("mac")) {
            globalCharset = MAC_ROMAN;
        }
    }
}
```